# Select nth element of a class CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a div with a number of image + text divs, the images and text divs appear in a random order, it could be `image-image-text-image` or `text-image-text-image` etc... each text item has a class associated with it, so how do I target the nth element of that class?

I can't target the parent as the first item may be an image or text and I only want to target each text item individually. This is the class applied to the variable number of divs in a variable order:

```
.article_content_divs {
    width:720px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you add the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-of-type(n)`. However, that requires you to use different **types** rather than different **classes**.

So instead of have `<div class="image">` and `<div class="text">`, you would need to have `<div class="image">` and `<p class="text">` for instance (or simply `<div>` and `<p>`, that's all that matters).

Then you can use `selectorforparent p:nth-of-type(n)`.

Note that `nth-of-type` is relatively recent, so you'll have to check backwards compatibility.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on safari mac

Comment: Works here. Not that your text and image elements must be different types (e.g. `p` vs `img`, or `p` vs `div`, or anything else you fancy), and you must include the type in the selector: `p:nth-of-type(3)`

Comment: he does not target types here, he wants to target ***classes***, that's why it does not work.